# Can I configure Apple Mail so that it does not cache any mails from Googlemail?

Tags: macos, mail.app, email

I'm using Apple Mail on Yosemite with my Gmail account(s). At the moment I have around 10 GB (!!) of mail database locally. Is there a way to use iMail so that it does not cache anything? It would then basically only work if there is any internet connection.

Comment: That is one of the reasons why I don't use Apple Mail any more. It seems to have no regard for disk space.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, there is no real possibility to disable the caching on mail.

What you could do is: reduce the IMAP folder size directly in Gmail :

> Settings > Forwarding and POP/IMAP > Folder Size Limits > Limit IMAP
>   folders to contain no more than this many messages = 1000